KeyError when accessing tuned signal data in backtest function
I'm working on a trading algorithm and encountering a KeyError while trying to access a column in a DataFrame. Specifically, I run into the error during the backtesting phase when accessing a tuned signal for a stock ticker.
KeyError: 'MSFT_Tuned_Signal'

Here’s the relevant part of my code:
def backtest_with_risk_management(data, tickers):
    for ticker in tickers:
        for i in range(len(data)):
            signal = data[f'{ticker}_Tuned_Signal'].iloc[i]
            # Additional logic here...

It seems like the signal column ('{ticker}_Tuned_Signal') is missing from the data DataFrame for some tickers (e.g., MSFT), but I don't know why this is happening. I already applied a Kalman filter to generate the signal but the column is still not being created.
What could be the possible reasons for this, and how can I ensure that the signal data is properly generated and accessible during backtesting?
I applied a Kalman filter to the stock data and expected it to generate a new column in the DataFrame for each ticker (e.g., MSFT_Tuned_Signal, GOOG_Tuned_Signal). The Kalman filter seemed to run without errors, but when I attempted to access these columns in the backtesting function, I encountered a KeyError. I expected the columns to exist in the DataFrame, but they are missing for some tickers, resulting in the error.

When you're calling that function are you sure that the data argument passed contains the 'MSFT_Tuned_Signal' column ?
you can simply check it by using
'MSFT_Tuned_Signal' in data.columns

